# WP_Query with specific category

Tags: wordpress

How can I modify the following to specify a category?

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to specifically specify category to equal 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out simply edit to be.

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, cat=>1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```